# Search the items in sharepoint by ModifiedBy Managed Property not yielding proper results

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, search-results

we require to search the documents by "**ModifiedBy**" Managed Property but if we search that in the search box of the document Library, we get the following results

- The Search display result for the word, Excel,PPT documents with the value for **ModifiedBy** with the Last person who has modified the content in those documents rather than updated meta data properties for the documents

but for the non office documents like(pdf, Text, other files) once any user change any metadata properties of the document with in sharepoint UI Then if we search by **ModifiedBy** managed property the results are shown with last modified (metadata changes)

can anybody explain how i can display the documents (Office) with  **ModifiedBy** managed property for which only content has changed ??